# how to find which date the consecutive column status "Complete" started with in a 7day period

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to get a date from below input on which there is a consecutive 'complete' status for past 7 days from that given date.

Requirement:
1. go Back 8 days (this is easy)
2. So we are on 20190111 from below data frame, I need to check day by day from 20190111 to 20190104 (7 day period) and get a date on which status has 'complete' for consecutive 7 days. So we should get 20190108
I need this in `spark-scala`.

input

```
+---+--------+--------+
| id|    date|  status|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1|20190101|complete|
|  2|20190102|complete|
|  3|20190103|complete|
|  4|20190104|complete|
|  5|20190105|complete|
|  6|20190106|complete|
|  7|20190107|complete|
|  8|20190108|complete|
|  9|20190109| pending|
| 10|20190110|complete|
| 11|20190111|complete|
| 12|20190112| pending|
| 13|20190113|complete|
| 14|20190114|complete|
| 15|20190115| pending|  
| 16|20190116| pending|
| 17|20190117| pending|
| 18|20190118| pending|
| 19|20190119| pending|
+---+--------+--------+
```

output

```
+---+--------+--------+
| id|    date|  status|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1|20190101|complete|
|  2|20190102|complete|
|  3|20190103|complete|
|  4|20190104|complete|
|  5|20190105|complete|
|  6|20190106|complete|
|  7|20190107|complete|
|  8|20190108|complete|
```

output

```
+---+--------+--------+
| id|    date|  status|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1|20190101|complete|
|  2|20190102|complete|
|  3|20190103|complete|
|  4|20190104|complete|
|  5|20190105|complete|
|  6|20190106|complete|
|  7|20190107|complete|
|  8|20190108|complete|
```

Comment: please include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for >= spark 2.4

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


val df= Seq((1,"20190101","complete"),(2,"20190102","complete"),
  (3,"20190103","complete"),(4,"20190104","complete"), (5,"20190105","complete"),(6,"20190106","complete"),(7,"20190107","complete"),(8,"20190108","complete"),
(9,"20190109", "pending"),(10,"20190110","complete"),(11,"20190111","complete"),(12,"20190112", "pending"),(13,"20190113","complete"),(14,"20190114","complete"),(15,"20190115", "pending") , (16,"20190116", "pending"),(17,"20190117", "pending"),(18,"20190118", "pending"),(19,"20190119", "pending")).toDF("id","date","status")


val df1=  df.select($"id", to_date($"date", "yyyyMMdd").as("date"), $"status")

val win = Window.orderBy("id")
```

coalesce lag_status and status to remove null

```
val df2= df1.select($"*", lag($"status",1).over(win).as("lag_status")).withColumn("lag_stat", coalesce($"lag_status", $"status")).drop("lag_status")
```

create integer columns to denote if staus for current day is equal to status for previous days

```
val df3=df2.select($"*", ($"status"===$"lag_stat").cast("integer").as("status_flag"))


val win1= Window.orderBy($"id".desc).rangeBetween(0,7)


val df4= df3.select($"*", sum($"status_flag").over(win1).as("previous_7_sum"))

val df_new= df4.where($"previous_7_sum"===8).select($"date").select(explode(sequence(date_sub($"date",7), $"date")).as("date"))

val df5=df4.join(df_new, Seq("date"), "inner").select($"id", concat_ws("",split($"date".cast("string"), "-")).as("date"), $"status")


+---+--------+--------+
| id|    date|  status|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1|20190101|complete|
|  2|20190102|complete|
|  3|20190103|complete|
|  4|20190104|complete|
|  5|20190105|complete|
|  6|20190106|complete|
|  7|20190107|complete|
|  8|20190108|complete|
+---+--------+--------+
```

for spark < 2.4

use udf instead of built in array function "sequence"

```
val df1=  df.select($"id", $"date".cast("integer").as("date"), $"status")

val win = Window.orderBy("id")
```

coalesce lag_status and status to remove null

```
 val df2= df1.select($"*", lag($"status",1).over(win).as("lag_status")).withColumn("lag_stat", coalesce($"lag_status", $"status")).drop("lag_status")
```

create integer columns to denote if staus for current day is equal to status for previous days

```
val df3=df2.select($"*", ($"status"===$"lag_stat").cast("integer").as("status_flag"))


val win1= Window.orderBy($"id".desc).rangeBetween(0,7)

val df4= df3.select($"*", sum($"status_flag").over(win1).as("previous_7_sum"))


val ud1= udf((col1:Int) => {
 ((col1-7).to(col1 )).toArray})

val df_new= df4.where($"previous_7_sum"===8)
  .withColumn("dt_arr", ud1($"date"))
  .select(explode($"dt_arr" ).as("date"))

val df5=df4.join(df_new, Seq("date"), "inner").select($"id", concat_ws("",split($"date".cast("string"), "-")).as("date"), $"status")
```

Comment: Thank you mikeL.. how did you do . val df_new= df4.where($"previous_7_sum"===8).select($"date").select(explode(sequence(date_sub($"date",7), $"date")).as("date")) .   for me its giving "error: not found: value sequence"

Comment: @xv7789 sequence in a 2.4 array function. If you are using < 2.4, then use a udf. I added the update.